# How can I solve a system of linear equations in python faster than with numpy.linalg.lstsq?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, math, computer-science

I am trying to solve a linear system spanning somewhat between hundred thousand and two hundred thousand equations with numpy.linalg.lstsq but is taking waaaaay too long. What can I do to speed this up?

The matrix is sparse with hundreds of columns (the dimensions are approximately 150 000 x 140) and the system is overdetermined.

Comment: Add more info please. Dimensions, dense vs. sparse, structure...

Comment: Alright , done it.

Comment: If it's sparse, [try the sparse solver](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit of improvised trickery that speeds up the computation quite a bit on random data of the indicated dimensions.

I've no idea how numerically sound this is, though.

```
import numpy as np
from time import perf_counter

def lstsq(A, b):
    AA = A.T @ A
    bA = b @ A
    D, U = np.linalg.eigh(AA)
    Ap = (U * np.sqrt(D)).T
    bp = bA @ U / np.sqrt(D)
    return np.linalg.lstsq(Ap, bp, rcond=None)

# create random data
A = np.random.random((150_000, 140))
b = np.random.random((150_000,))

# use solver directly
t = perf_counter()
x, *info = np.linalg.lstsq(A, b, rcond=None)
s = perf_counter()
print('direct method:     ', s-t, 'seconds')
# use equivalent reduced system
t = perf_counter()
x_acc, *info_acc = lstsq(A, b)
s = perf_counter()
print('accelerated method:', s-t, 'seconds')
print('results equal:', np.allclose(x, x_acc))
```

Sample run:

```
direct method:      3.032766239999546 seconds
accelerated method: 0.20947745100056636 seconds
results equal: True
```

Answer (score 0):

If your coefficient matrix is sparse, use "spsolve" from "scipy.sparse.linalg".